# visual studio 2010 odbc driver mysql, failed to call ODBC driver connection utility

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, odbc

n win7 64bits, I have Visual Studio 2010 SP1

```
MySql connector net 6.5.6
MySql connector odbc 5.2.5 winx64
```

On Localhost I have the MySql database and can connect with MySqlWorkbench. 
I have made a user-DSN and a system-DSN on the MySQL database.

In VS2010 I try to make a server Explorer- Data Connection with Micorsoft ODBC Data Source (ODBC) and select the system-data-source name and click OK.

Then I get the message 'Failed to call the ODBC driver connection utility'.

I have tried connector net 6.7.4, but than on a click the window 'add connection' disappears. Connector odbc 5.1.12 does not fix the problem.

In VS2005 on winXP with MySQL odbc 3.51 I can make a connection.

Is there something I miss for VS2010 ?

Deperate looking for a solution, after 2 days of trying :-(

Regards

Comment: have you tried installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable?

Comment: No, I don't have. Should I? Becourse normally I use Visual Basic.

Comment: I've installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable, but no sulotion.

Comment: Quote:`MySQL Connector/Net does not currently support Express versions of Microsoft products, including Microsoft Visual Web Developer.` check this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-visual-studio.html

Comment: I never use database integration in visual studio, only use connection string with import to `mysql.data.mysqlclient` and including the dll with the project.